# How do I use a Github program where the .exe does not exists?

Tags: github

I try to use programs or scripts on github form time to time, and several times I find myself incapable of executing the program and that is generally because the tutorial points towards a .exe or that does not exists on the github repository (folder containing all the gihub project files).

This is the perfect example :

https://github.com/agaboduarte/AliExpressScraper

This indicates that for using it you put

> alishop.exe -ProductId=32704963843

or

> alishop.exe -ProductUrl=https://pt.aliexpress.com/store/product/Original-Meizu-MEILAN-E-5-5-inch-2-5D-FHD-1080P-MTK-Helio-P10-Octa-Core/103919_32712980451.html?detailNewVersion=&categoryId=5090301&spm=a2g03.8047714.2169898.2.6F0m5X

As command line.

But there is no such file as 'alishop.exe' in this repo !

The only other .exe file that there is is NuGet.exe, so I tried to use

> NuGet.exe -ProductId=32704963843

Result : the command '-ProductId=32704963843' is said to be 'unknown' (command launched in the folder containing NuGet.exe of course)

Any idea of what do I do wrong ?

Comment: you are not doing anything wrong, the library author is not provided instructions as to how to "build" that exe. Normally, the authors would publish the exe somewhere else, or on github, or have instructions on how one should build it. The project you have linked has nothing of that sort. You could raise a github issue to ask the author this question. I doubt if anyone here can help you with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source code must typically be built or compiled. In this case, it's a C# project, and [expects you to have Visual Studio](https://github.com/agaboduarte/AliExpressScraper/blob/master/Maverick.sln).

In other cases, Github projects may simply be scripts, documents, or plugins. They may not be standalone executables, and you will need other tools to make use of them.